# Merge array of objects with underscore

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have array of objects like this. And they have duplicated property 'contactName' values

```
[
    {
        categoryId:1
        categoryName:"Default"
        contactId:141
        contactName:"Anonymous"
        name:"Mobile"
        value:"+4417087654"
    },
    {
        categoryId:1
        categoryName:"Default"
        contactId:325
        contactName:"Anonymous"
        name:"Email"
        value:"test2@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        categoryId:1
        categoryName:"Default"
        contactId:333
        contactName:"Anonymous"
        name:"Email"
        value:"ivdtest@test.com"
    }
]
```

I want to merge them in one object by the name of property 'contactName'
To something like this

```
[
    {
        categoryId: 1,
        categoryName: "Default",
        contactId: 141,
        contactName: "Anonymous",
        names: {
            1: "Mobile",
            2: "Email",
            3: "Email"
        },
        values: {
            1: '+2234324',
            2: "ivdtest@test.com",
            3: "test2@gmail.com"
        }
    }
];
```

**Edit:** How can I group objects also by `categoryName` ?

Comment: You just want to keep the first one's `contactId` value right..?

Comment: It seems you throw away the different `contactId`s. Is that intentional?

Comment: what will happen to contactId?

Comment: `contactId` could be from Array[0] value

Comment: A contact array inside the object would make more sense. Inside the array, each contact is an object `{ name: "Mobile", value: "+2234324" }`

Comment: @EmileBergeron agree. Added such variant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(input, 'contactName');
var output = _.map(grouped, function(entries) {
  return _.extend(
    _.pick(entries[0], 'categoryId', 'categoryName', 'contactId', 'contactName'), 
    {
      names: _.indexBy(_.pluck(entries, 'name'), function(val, index) { return index +1; }), 
      values: _.indexBy(_.pluck(entries, 'value'), function(val, index) { return index +1; })
    }
  );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f1x4tscu/3/

Answer (score 1):

Another variant with array inside the object

```
var grouped = _.groupBy(this.contacts, 'contactName');
var output = _.map(grouped, function (entries) {
    return _.extend(
        _.pick(entries[0], 'categoryId', 'categoryName', 'contactId', 'contactName'),
        {
            addresses: _.map(entries, function (m) {
                return {
                    name: m.name,
                    value: m.value
                }
            }),
        }
    );
});
```